# How to set limit in Cakephp sql query?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

This is my code in cakephp but here I use direct Sql condition. 
Can you please tell me, how to set limit in Cakephp.
This is my query. Please help me to convert in Cakephp query.

```
$Image4 = $this->Image->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_dhalao_image order by id desc limit 4,1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$this->set('tbl_dhalao_image', $this->Image->find('all', array(
    'limit' => 4,
    'offset' => 1
)));
```